# Complex analysis integration with logs

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, logarithms, contour-integration

> $$\int_C \operatorname{Log}\left(1-\frac 1 z \right)\,dz$$ where $C$ is the circle $|z|=2$

I don't even know how you would begin doing this.

I understand $\operatorname{Log}(z)=\ln|z|+i\arg(z)$, but I don't think it helps in this case.

Comment: you might try the fact that $1-\frac{1}{z}=\frac{z-1}{z}$

Comment: If no intelligent method is available to you, you could try dumb brute force and write $z = 2\cos\theta+2i\sin\theta$ so that $dz=(-2\sin\theta+2i\cos\theta)\,d\theta$ and $1/z=\frac 1 2 \cos\theta-\frac12 i\sin\theta$ and integrate from $\theta=0$ to $\theta=2\pi$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $\operatorname {Log} (1-w) = -(w+w^2/2 +w^3/3 + \cdots )$ for $|w|<1.$